# React Native Stripe Firebase - Test token working but test card undefined

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, payment

I am trying to send my charges to stripe through firebase cloud functions, when I send a test token such as "tok_mastercard" everything works fine.  Once I substitute for my token created by tipsi stripe firebase shows all information sent as undefined.  I have console logged my token in cloud functions and everything looks fine.

I feel like I am missing something obvious. Thanks in advance for any help.

FIREBASE CLOUD FUNCTION

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const stripe = require("stripe")(MY SECRET KEY);

exports.payWithStripe = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  stripe.charges
    .create({
      amount: request.body.amount,
      currency: request.body.currency,
      source: request.body.token,
    })
    .then((charge) => response.send(charge))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

CONSOLE LOGGED TOKEN

```
{"card": {"addressCity": "Macon", "addressCountry": "Estonia", "addressLine1": "Canary Place", "addressLine2": "3", "addressState": "", "addressZip": "31217", "brand": "Visa", "cardId": "card_1HdFN7C7qEwniOSJWxN2Tbs6", "country": "US", "expMonth": 1, "expYear": 2022, "funding": "credit", "isApplePayCard": false, "last4": "4242", "name": "Enappd Store"}, "created": 1602940977, "livemode": false, "tokenId": "tok_1HdFN7C7qEwniOSJc1nUQcqH"}
```

GENERATE TOKEN WITH TIPSI STRIPE

```
  stripe.setOptions({
    publishableKey:"MY TEST KEY",});

  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);


  const handleCardPayPress = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      setToken(null);
      const token = await stripe.paymentRequestWithCardForm({
        smsAutofillDisabled: true,
        requiredBillingAddressFields: "full",
        prefilledInformation: {
          billingAddress: {
            name: "Enappd Store",
            line1: "Canary Place",
            line2: "3",
            city: "Macon",
            state: "",
            country: "Estonia",
            postalCode: "31217",
            email: "admin@enappd.com",
          },
        },
      });
      setToken(token);
      console.log(token);
      setLoading(false);
      Alert.alert("Your card information has been entered!");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

HANDLE CHECKOUT

```
    fetch("MY CLOUD FUNCTIONS URL", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        amount: cartTotalAmount,
        currency: "usd",
        token: token,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

FIREBASE LOG

```
9:43:09.377 AM
payWithStripe
statusCode: 400,
9:43:09.377 AM
payWithStripe
charge: undefined,
9:43:09.377 AM
payWithStripe
decline_code: undefined,
9:43:09.377 AM
payWithStripe
payment_intent: undefined,
9:43:09.377 AM
payWithStripe
payment_method: undefined,
9:43:09.377 AM
payWithStripe
setup_intent: undefined,
9:43:09.377 AM
payWithStripe
source: undefined }
9:44:08.752 AM
payWithStripe
Function execution took 60008 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
```

Comment: I answered my own questions by setting setToken(token) to setToken(token.tokenId)

Comment: HI, I have added the answer as a community wiki, could you please accept it?  Additionally, when you find the answer fell free to post it as answer and accept it, in this way, other community members can identify easily the solution to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change:

```
setToken(token)
```

to

```
setToken(token.tokenId)
```